# Django Image field unable to change or remove existing image

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, imagefield

I am trying to update an image in the Django Admin but when I check the 'clear' checkbox and save it, nothing happens. Also when I try to replace the existing image with a new nothing happens. 
The strange part is that I am using the exact code in a different model and its working fine there.

Please note that the image gets saved to the desired location at the time of first creating the object in Django admin. But then when I try to edit it, nothing happens.

My model looks something like this -

```
class Community(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(
            upload_to=upload_location,
            null=True,
            blank=True,
            width_field="width_field",
            height_field="height_field", help_text="A image representing 
            the Community")
    height_field = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Also my upload_location function looks like this -

```
def upload_location(instance, filename):
    return "community_banners/%s/%s" % (instance.name, filename)
```

The things I have tried are - changing the upload location, deleting the model and recreating it. But nothing seems to work.

I am using django 2.0

Comment: Are there any logs in your server that show errors?

Comment: No there aren't any error messages shown, it just shows the message that the object is saved in the django admin but the image remains as is

Comment: Just create a before save callback and delete image using image path .

Comment: Yes that is a possible solution, but my question is why I'm unable to do it via admin and why does no change occur after I hit save,